# How can I write a php script that downloads one of several songs on a page?

Tags: php, download

I have a page with songs on it and a download button next to each song:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Off the Grid</td>
    <td><a href="http://example.com/php/download.php?Off_the_Grid.mp3">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Far-Sighted</td>
    <td><a href="http://example.com/php/download.php?Far_Sighted.mp3">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then I have the following script that forces a download:

```
<?php

    $audioFile = "Off_the_Grid.mp3";
    $fileName = $_GET['$audioFile'];
    // Fetch the file info.
    $filePath = '../audio/' . $audioFile;

    if(file_exists($filePath)) {
        $fileName = basename($filePath);
        $fileSize = filesize($filePath);

        // Output headers.
        header("Cache-Control: private");
        header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3");
        header("Content-Length: ".$fileSize);
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName);

        // Output file.
        readfile ($filePath);                   
        exit();
    }
    else {
        die('The provided file path is not valid.');
    }

?>
```

My goal is to turn this script into a function such that when the download link of a song is clicked -- e.g., "Far-Sighted" -- "Far-Sighted" and only "Far-Sighted" is forced to download. And if instead the "Off the Grid" download link is clicked, the function will run for "Off the Grid".  And etc. for all the songs I post.

The above code works insofar as it forces the download of "Off the Grid". But, I'm trying to get it to force the download for any song that is clicked.  Right now, if I clicked on "Download" next to "Far-Sighted" then according to my posted code, "Off the Grid" would download and "Far-Sighted" would not download.  Obviously, "Far-Sighted" should download; however, I'm stuck :-/

Is there a way to do this cleanly? I've been trying to think of a way to do this to no concise avail.  Is there a way to make it so that my variable "$audiofile" changes its value depending on what song download link is clicked?  I was going to resort to creating php files for each song and just post the script unique to the song there, or just one php file with several instances of the script tailored to each song. But that seemed ridiculous.

Is there a nice way to make this happen? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I believe that is being the problem is the fact that you're not using the GET correctly. I'll try to make myself as clear as possible:

Any url with ? will be parsed by GET, and the keys will be given the following way:

```
example.com?key=value&key2=value2
```

Therefore, look again at how you're parsing the GET values. You could take a look at this tutorial if you want: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php

I would suggest the following solution:

```
  <tr>
    <td>Far-Sighted</td>
    <td><a href="http://example.com/php/download.php?id=Far_Sighted.mp3">Download</a></td>
  </tr>
```

And the php

```
$audioFile = $_GET['id'];
// Fetch the file info.
$filePath = '../audio/' . $audioFile;
```

Take into account that it's a good idea to verify any data comming from GET to avoid injections.

Comment: Thanks for answering! The force download works for both ".../download.php?Far_Sighted.mp3" and for ".../download.php?farSighted=Far_Sighted.mp3".  It's not forcing the download that's the problem, but how to use 1 instance of the script that runs for whatever song is clicked.  Is that the question you are answering or am I misunderstanding your answer?

Comment: My point was that I think you're not using GET correctly and the filepath will always be `$filePath = '../audio/' . "Off_the_Grid.mp3"` instead of being variable on the song clicked. 

So, to be clear:  
- Make sure you're getting the info you want with GET
- Make sure that file_path is pointing where you want

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks.  Elegantly simple :)

Comment: You're welcome! :)
Remember to play safe with GET, as any data may be introduced there.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with post? I'm very new to all this so I don't really understand all the potential security problems. Thanks, again!

Comment: I don't think it's necessary. As long as you make sure code can not be injected, you'll be fine. A good way to avoid this is applying `htmlspecialchars()` to any GET. You can look for more info in php.net, f.e. in this comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php#105335